# Weak maximum principle for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Consider $u(x,t)$ as the solution of the equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u-\Delta u=f(x,t)$$
for $(x,t) \in \Omega \times [0,T]$

Using the weak maximum principle and its prerequisites I need to show that for $f(x,t) <0$ in $\Omega \times [0,T]$, u attains its maximum on $\partial(\Omega \times [0,T])$.

I think the differential operator is given as $Lu=\Delta u=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u-f(x,t)$. It's clear that $-f(x,t)$ is positive but how could I show that the derivative of $u$ is positive as well. This should give me the desired result?

Comment: Could I maybe prove this using contradiction? Assuming the maximum is attained in the interior then the gradient is 0 and thus Lu becomes just $-f(x,t)$ which is positive. This means according to the weak maximum principle that the maximum of u is attained at the boundary which is a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $u \in C^2_1(\Omega_T) \cap C(\overline \Omega_T)$ where $\Omega_T:=\Omega \times (0,T]$. Since $f(x,t)<0$ in $\Omega_T$, $u$ is a subsolution of the heat equation. Hence, the maximum principle tells us $$\max_{\overline \Omega_T} u = \max_{\Gamma_T}u$$ where $\Gamma_T$ is the parabolic boundary of $\Omega_T$. That is, $u$, attains its maximum on $ \Gamma_T \subset \partial (\Omega \times (0,T))$.